# inflections on rails 3.2 for other languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 languages in an app: **English** and **Spanish**.

I have an object named `Job` and `Job` has and attribute integer named `max_day_on_complete`

In my view in english language I have:

```
<%= pluralize(@job.max_day_on_complete, 'day') %>
```

I get with this an output:

```
1 day
2 days
3 days
.
.
.
```

In Spanish, `day = día` and `days = días`

But when I change my app to Spanish, I can not see `día, días` words.

How can show in my view this words when I have my app in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the problem was fixed.

In `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add:

```
# encoding: utf-8
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
inflect.irregular('día', 'días')
end
```

In your view for example:

```
<%= pluralize(@job.max_day_on_complete, t('.max_day_on_complete')) %>
```

in your `es.yml`

```
jobs:
   show:
       max_day_on_complete: "día"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to hyperrjas' answer for people who land here

I had to add the locale symbol to get this working like so:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:ar) do |inflect|
    # your inflections here
end
```